# Restart pm2 if cpu overloaded

Tags: node.js, pm2

How can I restart my pm2 if usage of CPU = 100%? If CPU's usage reaches 100%, server and ssh freze and can't connect to the server.

Comment: If your CPU is overloading, i don't think adding another task to it (restarting pm2) is good. Either scale up your instance or prevent the overload.

Comment: @snitron Did you find any solution?